# Android HttpUrlConnection hangs on getResponseCode()

Tags: android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

So, from my (android) api I am trying to login to my web service by posting username and password to the login page. The server should then redirect either to a success url, or an error url, depending on whether the the authentication is successful or not.

The code reads as follows:

```
String urlParameters = "_username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
                            + "&_password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

URL url = new URL(MainActivity.I_SAIL_URL + "/member/login_check");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("api", "requestKey");

connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
//connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

//Send request
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

// if there is a response code AND that response code is 200 OK, do
// stuff in the first if block
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Now, everything works fine in an android 6.0 emulator, but it doesn't work on an actual device running on 4.1.2. When i uncomment the `connection.setReadTimeout()`, it will throw a timeout exception, if i don't it will run for about 10 to 15 minutes and then sometimes give me the expected result.

The problem occurs only when the server redirects. If there is no redirect, everything is fine. I have tried `HttpUrlConnection.setFollowRedirects(true)` as well as `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)`, to no success.

Any ideas what can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: I think i found the answer. The problem was that my testing device got wet that morning. Since then it has been slowly falling apart and dying. I'll post this as an answer as soon as i get a possibility to test it on a properly working real device and be 100% sure...